# Text of button in ListView Item is changed while scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` and i populated that `ListView` with `TextView` and Button using custom adapter.I had generated a click event for that `Button` in `custom adapter`.In that click event i am trying to change the button text and color,up to here its working fine but when i scroll the `ListView` up and down the text color of other button changing. I had stop here from past couple of days...

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Activity a;
ArrayList<String> Rollno;
ArrayList<String> Stdname;
ArrayList<String> Stdstatus;

public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> rollno, ArrayList<String> stdname, ArrayList<String> stdstatus) {
    this.a = a;
    Rollno = rollno;
    Stdname = stdname;
    Stdstatus = stdstatus;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return Rollno.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return Rollno.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public  class ViewHolder{
    TextView rollno,name;
    Button status;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     final  ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
    View v=li.inflate(R.layout.custom,parent,false);
    viewHolder.rollno=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.crollno);
    viewHolder.name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cname);
    viewHolder.status=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);


    viewHolder.rollno.setText(Rollno.get(position));
    viewHolder.name.setText(Stdname.get(position));
    viewHolder.status.setText(Stdstatus.get(position));

   viewHolder.status.setTag(0);
    viewHolder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           final int status1 = (Integer) v.getTag();

            if (status1 == 1) {
                viewHolder.status.setText("P");
                viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                v.setTag(0);
            } else if (status1 == 2) {
                viewHolder.status.setText("A");
                viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                v.setTag(1);
            } else if (status1 == 3) {
                viewHolder.status.setText("L");
                viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                v.setTag(2);
            } else {
                viewHolder.status.setText("H");
                viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                v.setTag(3);

            }

        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: You have that problem because the ListView is reusing cells and thus the state of previously cell is displayed. You need to store the sate of the button somewhere and check the state in ```getView```.

Comment: how can i store state of button.i am new in android can u give me that code.Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to store status for position.
Replace your adapter with below code.

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Activity a;
        ArrayList<String> Rollno;
        ArrayList<String> Stdname;
        ArrayList<String> Stdstatus;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> statusArray = new HashMap<>();

        public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> rollno, ArrayList<String> stdname, ArrayList<String> stdstatus) {
            this.a = a;
            Rollno = rollno;
            Stdname = stdname;
            Stdstatus = stdstatus;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Rollno.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return Rollno.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public  class ViewHolder{
            TextView rollno,name;
            Button status;
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final  ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater li=a.getLayoutInflater();
            View v=li.inflate(R.layout.custom,parent,false);
            viewHolder.rollno=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.crollno);
            viewHolder.name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.cname);
            viewHolder.status=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);


            viewHolder.rollno.setText(Rollno.get(position));
            viewHolder.name.setText(Stdname.get(position));
            viewHolder.status.setText(Stdstatus.get(position));

            int status = statusArray.get(position) != null ? statusArray.get(position) : 0;
            switch (status){
                case 1:
                    viewHolder.status.setText("P");
                    viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewHolder.status.setText("A");
                    viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewHolder.status.setText("L");
                    viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                default:
                    viewHolder.status.setText("H");
                    viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;
            }

            viewHolder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int status1 = statusArray.get(position) != null ? statusArray.get(position) : 0;
                    if (status1 == 1) {
                        statusArray.put(position, 0);
                    } else if (status1 == 2) {
                        statusArray.put(position, 1);
                    } else if (status1 == 3) {
                        statusArray.put(position, 2);
                    } else {
                        statusArray.put(position, 3);
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting your tag which leads to your button logic not working correctly.

```
viewHolder.status.setTag(0);
```

Usualy you do something like that:

```
if (convertview == null){
  //create and initialize new viewholder and pass it to the views tag field
  //initialize the status tag here and dont set it again later
}else{
 //get your viewholder from the views tag
}
//update your values
```

[Example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

/*
 * The convertView argument is essentially a "ScrapView" as described is Lucas post 
 * http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/
 * It will have a non-null value when ListView is asking you recycle the row layout. 
 * So, when convertView is not null, you should simply update its contents instead of inflating a new row layout.
 */
if(convertView==null){

    // inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    // well set up the ViewHolder
    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

    // store the holder with the view.
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

}else{
    // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
    // just use the viewHolder
    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}

// object item based on the position
ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];

// assign values if the object is not null
if(objectItem != null) {
    // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
    viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(objectItem.itemName);
    viewHolder.textViewItem.setTag(objectItem.itemId);
}

return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use card view same problem i faced use like that.

```
              if (readvalue.equals("0")) {
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.texthintcolor));
        //  holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(0);
        //cardView.setRadius(5);

    } else {
        //     holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor());
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.winter));


        // cardView.setRadius(5);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

place this 'viewHolder.status.setTag(0);' below to onClickListener i think it will work

```
 viewHolder.status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       final int status1 = (Integer) v.getTag();

        if (status1 == 1) {
            viewHolder.status.setText("P");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            v.setTag(0);
        } else if (status1 == 2) {
            viewHolder.status.setText("A");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            v.setTag(1);
        } else if (status1 == 3) {
            viewHolder.status.setText("L");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            v.setTag(2);
        } else {
            viewHolder.status.setText("H");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            v.setTag(3);

        }

    }
});
viewHolder.status.setTag(0);
return v;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

The views are recreated each time they come foreground so only view position can really be unique.
Rather than using view tags,you could create a Hashmap of view position and  your own tag(Integer). Each time view is created, you check if position exist in hashmap and set button colour according to hashmap tag. Place the line

```
private HashMap<Integer,Integer> tagMap = new HashMap<>();
```

in beginning of customAdapter. In getView check if position has been added, if not add it with corresponding button tag

```
int tag=1; //desired default tag for button
   //add to hashmap if not exist
 if(!tagMap.containsKey(position)){
        tagMap.put(position,tag);
    }
```

In onclick listerner, you could get hasmap tag by position and set button colour accordingly

```
   final int status1 = tagMap.get(position);;

        if (status1 == 1) {
            viewHolder.status.setText("P");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            tagMap.put(position,0);//this will update tag for current position
        } else if (status1 == 2) {
            viewHolder.status.setText("A");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
           tagMap.put(position,1);
        } else if (status1 == 3) {
            viewHolder.status.setText("L");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tagMap.put(position,2);
        } else {
            viewHolder.status.setText("H");
            viewHolder.status.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
          tagMap.put(position,3);
        }
```

Hope this helps