# "Add to favorites" button in recyclerview using CheckedTextView

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-recyclerview

### ANDROID: "Add to favorites" button in recyclerview using CheckedTextView?

In this data fetch from server and click view not update

My problem is that:On click of (favorites) button when I'm scrolling the view, it changes the position of that clicked button.

---

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      if (holder instanceof StudentViewHolder) {
        OfficeData list = (OfficeData) adapterList.get(position);
        final HashMap < String, Object > detailMap = list.getMapMain();
        try {

          ((StudentViewHolder) holder).gView.setTag(list.getMapMain());

          if (detailMap.containsKey((ConstVariable.FAVOURITESTATUS)) && detailMap.get(ConstVariable.FAVOURITESTATUS) != null) {

            if (detailMap.get(ConstVariable.FAVOURITESTATUS).toString().equals("red")) {
              Log.e("testing", "3");
              ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_green);
              ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (detailMap.get(ConstVariable.FAVOURITESTATUS).toString().equals("default")) {
              Log.e("testing", "4");
              ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);
              ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setChecked(false);

            }
          }
        }


        ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

          {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              if (((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.isChecked()) {


                Utils.global.mapData.clear();
                Utils.global.mapData.put(ConstVariable.MODE, (ConstVariable.UNFAV).toString()); //used for unFavorite  
                ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);
                ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setChecked(false);

                Utils.global.mapData.put(ConstVariable.VIDEOPOSTID, detailMap.get(ConstVariable.VIDEOID).toString());
                JsonPost.getAddFavorite(Utils.context, null, "ASC", "");



                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Utils.context, "Unfavourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
              } else {
                Utils.global.mapData.clear();

                Utils.global.mapData.put(ConstVariable.MODE, (ConstVariable.FAV).toString()); //used for Favorite 
                Utils.global.mapData.put(ConstVariable.VIDEOPOSTID, detailMap.get(ConstVariable.VIDEOID).toString());
                ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_green);
                ((StudentViewHolder) holder).imagehart.setChecked(true);

                JsonPost.getAddFavorite(Utils.context, null, "ASC", "");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Utils.context, "Favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                Log.e("click", "2");
              }
            }
          }
        );

      } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.e("EventDataAdapter 155", "Exception======================Exception======================Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      ((StudentViewHolder) holder).officeData = list;
    }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
      loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      if (adapterList != null) {
        return adapterList.size();
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
    public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public View gView;
      public OfficeData officeData;

      CheckedTextView imagehart;

      public StudentViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        this.setIsRecyclable(false);
        gView = v;
        try {
          imagehart = (CheckedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_hart);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Utils.e("ProfileEventRecycle 173", "Exception======================Exception======================Exception");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public ProgressBar progressBar;

      public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar12);
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to store state. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203126/text-of-button-in-listview-item-is-changed-while-scrolling/42203562#42203562

Comment: In your model/pojo class declare a `boolean flag = false;` and change it `true` on click. and check if flag true set text whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks :- Pratik Popat and Devendra Singh , But problem not solved